# Proving that every edge in a graph must belong to a $K_4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I've been asked to prove the following statement;

> Let $G$ be a graph of order $n \ge 4$. Prove that if $\deg_G(v) \ge \frac{2n+1}{3}$ for every vertex in $G$, then every edge of $G$ belongs to a complete subgraph of order 4.

I'm really quite lost in even trying to begin this question. I was hoping to apply Turan's theorem, and use some manipulation of the binomial coefficients of this theorem, but I'm still not sure what I should be aiming for with this.

Any insights would be fantastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*: Let $(u,v)$ be an edge, and let $N(u)$ and $N(v)$ be the neighbours of $u$ and $v$ amongst $V(G)\setminus \{u,v\}.$ Show that $$\left|N(u)\cap N(v)\right|\geq \frac{n+2}{3}\geq 2.$$

Now, must there be an edge between two vertices in $N(u)\cap N(v)$?

Comment: With the way you've defined $N(u)$ and $N(v)$, I've got that $\left|N(u)\right| = \left|N(v)\right| = \frac{2n-2}{3}$, but I'm not sure how to consider what their intersection would be.

Comment: I've been thinking about it a bit more, and I know that the intersection of $N(u)$ and $N(v)$ must be, at maximum, equal to $n-2$, because, if we remove $u$ and $v$, we're left with a graph that has $n-2$ vertices, but I'm not too sure where to go from here, or how to say something about the intersection.

Comment: @Jack Well, you just know $|N(v)|,|N(u)|\ge\frac{2n-2}{3}$, and $|N(u)\cup N(v)|\leq n-2.$ Now apply the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: So many things coming back from my first year graph theory course ><

Thank you!!

Comment: I know it's pretty much giving away the question, but I'm having a difficult time conceptualising how to get an edge between the two vertices connected to both $u$ and $v$. From the intersection of $N(u)$ and $N(v)$, I know that the endpoints of any edge in $G$ are connected to at least two common vertices, but I don't know whether that helps, especially when I'm not certain that those two vertices are connected to each other.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your thought process there, but just pick any vertex $w\in N(u)\cap N(v)$. At least how many neighbours of $w$ are there in $V(G)\setminus\{u,v\}$? On the other hand, how many vertices are there (at most) in $V(G)\setminus\{u,v\}$ that are *not* in $N(u)\cap N(v)$?

Comment: Okay, so, if we consider any $w$ in $N(u) \cap N(v)$, then the degree of $w$ in $G \setminus\{u,v\}$ is at least $\frac{2n+1}{3} - 2 = \frac{2n-5}{3} \ge 1$. Then, there's at least one edge between two vertices of $N(u) \cap N(v)$, and we're finished??

Comment: Well, because there are at most $n-2-\frac{n+2}{3}$ vertices in $G\setminus((N(u)\cap N(v))\cup\{u,v\})$ which is less than $\frac{2n-5}{3}$, so one of the edges out of $w$ must go into $N(u)\cap N(v)$.